# What is a Squad Spot?

Tags: battlefield-1

In Battlefield 1, there is a medal called "Legion of the Wolf" currently active for me, with 3 days remaining on it. The first accolade for the medal is "Get 10 Squad Spots"; what in the world is a squad spot? I can spot enemies, but what counts towards my 10 points?

Comment: As a side note, if you see a Doritos above a player's head, it because he's been spotted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you spot an enemy (Q on PC while looking at him) you can gain a spot assist if he gets killed while he's having the class icon over his head.

A squad spot is basically the same but someone of your squad has to kill the spotted player.

Basically the best way to get this achievement is to simply mash your spot button all day if you see an enemy. (This will also result in a nice amount of bonus score)

Comment: That will do it, thanks. This is my first Battlefield game, so it's all new to me.

Comment: To clarify, you are awarded a certain number of XP points (50 IIRC - this is the number that will pop up on screen when it happens) for each instance of a squadmate killing an enemy you spotted.  To complete that stage of the medal, you need 10 instances of a squadmate killing an enemy you spotted (so 50*10=500 XP points worth of bonuses).